# gulp livereload not working

Tags: javascript, python, gulp, gulp-watch

I have this weird problem after installing the following gulp packages. Everything renders just fine, but when it gets to the part of the liveReload() it just doesn't reload the page...

I installed the livereload chrome extension (is it necessary?), and it seems like there is nothing to config there...

Here is my gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    autoPrefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    jade = require('gulp-jade'),
    liveReload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    sourceMaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    ts = require('gulp-typescript'),
    tsLint = require('gulp-tslint'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass');

// Configuration
var config = {
    js: 'public/_assets/frontend/js',
    css: 'public/_assets/frontend/css',
    fonts: 'public/_assets/frontend/fonts',
    images: 'public/_assets/frontend/img',
    markup: 'public/'
};

// Javascript
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    var tsResult = gulp.src(['src/ts/*.ts', 'src/ts/**/*.ts'])
        .pipe(tsLint())
        .pipe(ts({
            noImplicitAny: true
        }));

        tsResult.js
            .pipe(gulp.dest(config.js))
            .pipe(liveReload());
});

// Sass
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src(['src/sass/*.scss', 'src/sass/**/*.scss'])
        .pipe(watch(['src/sass/*.scss', 'src/sass/**/*.scss']))
        .pipe(sourceMaps.init())
        .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoPrefixer({
            browsers: ['last 3 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(sourceMaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.css))
        .pipe(liveReload());
});

// jade
gulp.task('markup', function() {
    return gulp.src(['src/**/*.jade', 'src/**/_*.jade'])
        .pipe(jade({
            pretty: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.markup))
        .pipe(liveReload());
});

// Images
gulp.task('images', function() {
    return gulp.src(['src/images/**/*.*', 'src/images/*.*'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.images));
});

// Watch
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    liveReload.listen();
    gulp.watch(['src/ts/*.ts', 'src/ts/**/*.ts'], ['scripts']);
    gulp.watch(['src/sass/*.scss', 'src/sass/**/*.scss'], ['sass']);
    gulp.watch(['src/*.jade', 'src/**/*.jade'], ['markup']);
});

// Default Task
gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.start('sass', 'scripts', 'markup', 'images', 'watch');
});
```

Everything works just fine, the gulp is doing it's thing and rendering all my files, but the page won't reload... I'm using python simple http server on port 8000.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that comes to my mind is: did you include the livereload client script into your page? AFAIK you should be supposed to inject this script at the end of your page's body.

```
<script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

[Live Reload Browser Page](https://live-reload-browser-page.com/)

[GitHub](https://github.com/Yuriy-Svetlov/live-reload-bp)

**Live Reload Browser Page** is very flexible tool for live reloading of the browser page.